Reference frame used to calculate torque in $\boldsymbol{\tau} = \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{F}$
I know that in $\tau = I \alpha$, we are present in frame of axis. When we write $\boldsymbol{\tau} = \mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{F}$, are we present in the frame of the point about which torque is to be calculated?

The latter is the definition of torque.
\begin{equation}
\vec{\tau}^{(O)}
=
\vec{r}^{(O)}
\times
\vec{F}
\end{equation}
Note that the torque depends on the origin since the position vector naturally does.
The former one is the time derivative of angular momentum.
\begin{equation}
\vec{L}^{(O)}
=
I^{(O)}
\vec{\Omega}
\end{equation}
This equation (and its derivative) doesn't hold for any reference frame.
Finally
\begin{equation}
\vec{\tau}
=
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}
\vec{L}
\end{equation}
is Newton's 2° law and also holds always (in Newtonian/Classical Mechanics, of course).

The equations $\vec\tau=I\vec\alpha$ and $\vec\tau=\vec r\times\vec F$ are equivalent; they each give an expression for torque with respect to the same frame of reference.
